Entity not saving on my db? No logs error
I started some crud basic project and I am using JPARepository to save on my database, but it´s not working.
I don't have any log error, just don't save. My db settings are right on my application properties and I am running SQL Server on the right port on podman
Here's my classes:
My Repository:
package com.bonbap.mycrudproject;

import com.bonbap.mycrudproject.model.Cliente;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, String> {
}


My entity:
package com.bonbap.mycrudproject.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "t1209Clt")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_clt", nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "nm_clt", nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "num_clt", nullable = false)
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "nm_tel", nullable = false)
    private String telefone;


My service saving method:
@Log4j2
@Service
@Transactional
public class ClienteService extends DefaultService implements CrudService  {

    private final ClienteRepository repository;

    private final ClienteMapper mapper;

    public ClienteService(ClienteRepository repository, ClienteMapper mapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incluirCliente(IncluirClienteRequestDTO request) {
        log.info("Incluindo cliente na base de dados...");
        log.trace("Incluir cliente: {}", request);
        salvarCliente(request);
        return true;
    }

    private Cliente salvarCliente(IncluirClienteRequestDTO request) {
        Cliente cliente = mapper.requestToModel(request);
        return repository.save(cliente);
    }

    public IncluirClienteRequestDTO buscarClientePorId() {
        log.info("Buscando cliente por id");
        log.trace("Buscar cliente por id: {}", id);
        List<Cliente> cliente = repository.findAll();
        if (cliente == null) {
            throw new ClienteNaoEncontradoException("Cliente não cadastrado.");
        }
        return mapper.modelToRequest(null);
    }
}

My pom:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bonbap</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyCrudProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyCrudProject</name>
    <description>MyCrudProject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.220</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:1460/bon_dsv</url>
                    <user>sa</user>
                    <password>Passw0rd</password>
                    <sqlMigrationPrefix>V</sqlMigrationPrefix>
                    <sqlMigrationSeparator>__</sqlMigrationSeparator>
                    <locations>
                        <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migrations/sql</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId> <!-- IMPORTANT - LOMBOK BEFORE MAPSTRUCT -->
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6.0</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


and my application.yml:
spring:
    application:
        name: MyCrudProject
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1460;databaseName=bon_dsv;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
        username: sa
        password: Passw0rd
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: true
        defer-datasource-initialization: true

I am expecting to save the information on my db, but its not happening nothing.

your spanish code is confusing me slightly ^^ haha

are you sure this is your working code? in method buscarClientePorId you refere to an id which is nowhere defined...

how do you know that the data is not stored in the database? you always return empty result: return mapper.modelToRequest(null); -> why null

Remove the jaxb-api that is an old one and incompatible. Remove jakarta.persistence-api that is part of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa already and in the proper supported version. Remove jakarta.validation-api and add spring-boot-starter-validation instead. Finally your buscarClientePorId always returns nothing due to return mapper.modelToRequest(null);.

@MartinFrankthe id is in my DTO, i forgot to post the git link. https://github.com/henribon/MyCrudProject/tree/feature_hbon%23
I will update my code to english and try to be more clear.

@M.Deinum i will update my pom and come with updates.
